# Stop showing Alert to rate app once it has been rated

Tags: android

i am trying the code to show users to rate my app

however once the user has rated the app it should not show again

how can that be done

moreover can we track if users have rated our app, is there any google api for this feature , can analytics be helpfull for tracking ratings of an app

```
public class AppRater {
    private final static String APP_TITLE = "App Name";// App Name
    private final static String APP_PNAME = "com.example.name";// Package Name

    private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;//Min number of days
    private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;//Min number of launches

    public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        // Increment launch counter
        long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
        editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

        // Get date of first launch
        Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 0);
        if (date_firstLaunch == 0) {
            date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
            editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
        }

        // Wait at least n days before opening
        if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch + 
                    (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
                showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
            }
        }

        editor.commit();
    }   

    public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
        tv.setWidth(240);
        tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
        ll.addView(tv);

        Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
        b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });        
        ll.addView(b1);

        Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
        b2.setText("Remind me later");
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b2);

        Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
        b3.setText("No, thanks");
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editor != null) {
                    editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b3);

        dialog.setContentView(ll);        
        dialog.show();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> moreover can we track if users have rated our app, is there any google
>   api for this feature , can analytics be helpfull for tracking ratings
>   of an app

=> There isn't such official API available yet!

And SharedPreference is not gonna be helpful as there isn't any such API available, using which you would be able to track whether user has rated already!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Shared Preferences [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

whenever user rate your app you set the boolean variable to true and makes the check before showing the rate app dialog if the user has already rated it or not if your boolean variable is false you can ask the user to rate the app, otherwise user has already rated your app,Shared Preferences are app level variables that stores the data even you close the app they only get destroyed when you remove the app from your device or clear the data under the Applications in Android.

Comment: shared preferences are already being used, the question is whether we can know if user has rated an app then stop showing the rate my app alert

Comment: Shared preference is not gonna be helpful. Tell me, how you would be able to track whether user has rated the app or not!

Comment: No. You cannot do this,there is no callback from Google API when you rate an app,all you can do is check in your code.

Comment: @PareshMayani all i am saying is we cannot track whether user has rated our app 100%,but what can we do is we can put a check inside method of onclick of rate button so that whenever user taps the rate button you count  it occurrence,this is the level of implementation we can achieve in this scenario

Comment: @ArslanSohail but that won't be helpful because if I just click on rate button and it will take me to play store but what If I just came back to app without rating!

Comment: yes true,i agree,i already said this is not the 100% solution but this can be helpful to an extent.